# too many ticks on log colorscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working in a `Jupyter` notebook with `Python 3.9.12` and  `matplotlib 3.5.2`. I am trying to plot a contour plot using `contourf` with a logarithmic "z" or "colorscale."

The code that I'm using is here:

```
#set up a 1d plot
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9.0,8.0),sharex=True)
ax1 = axes
from matplotlib import cm, ticker


ymin=1.0
ymax=15
xmin=4.0
xmax=45


zzN = np.nan_to_num(zzN)
z = ma.masked_where((zzN<=1e-3)|(zzN>0.2), zzN)
nrcont=ax1.contourf(p1,q1,z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(), cmap='coolwarm',alpha=0.3)


cbar = fig.colorbar(nrcont)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('joint PDF',labelpad=15)


ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax) #in pairs
ax1.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax1.set_xlabel('phonon energy [keV]')
ax1.set_ylabel('charge energy [keV]')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.yaxis.grid(True,which='minor',linestyle='--')
#ax1.legend(loc=2,prop={'size':22})

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
  ax1.spines[axis].set_linewidth(2)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

The object `zzN` are the contour values that I am plotting and they range from something like `10^-320` to about `0.13`. Because of that huge range I masked it down in the variable `z` to go over just 2 decades instead. I would like to go to 4 decades for this plot.

The result is the following plot:

[image: contour plot]

It's obvious that the colorscale is log but it is for some reason trying to give me ticks that are spaced 0.0025 apart. This is fine for the first decade of the scale, but for the last decade it results in a huge amount of ticks.

How can I get the normal "log" ticks back where each decade has 10 ticks logarithmically spaced?

Also: when I don't severely limit my z range (like if I try to start at 1e-4 instead of 1e-3) there are so many ticks that I get:

```
Locator attempting to generate 4444 ticks ([0.000325, ..., 1.0]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000).
```